# Can I randomise a page background across all my pages?

Tags: backgrounds

I have a folder with X images, I would like to randomise this as background for all pages.

Is there a good package for this?

Comment: Consider using `tikz`

Comment: how are the images named?

Comment: Create an array of file names (either tikz array or \csname array).  The only remining question is whether you want duplicates or a random sort.

Comment: Let's go with numbered :) Still array and tikz?